# docker container running on untrusted host machine

Tags: docker

I know that docker containers which are running on a host machine have root privileges.

I want to start a container using `HTTP requests` from a web app but I don't trust the host machine which is running docker.

Is it possible to make my container as a `"black-box"` so I can prevent even the root in the host machine from accessing it?

What I want is to simply run it?

Are there any other alternatives instead of docker that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK, no, there is no way to achieve that with Docker.

Docker container is a process that runs in isolated environment, but root user of the host the container runs on can access it's docker daemon and for example run exec to access shell in container.

Comment: Thanks, so in case I have some data that I process inside the container, the data will be accessible from the root user of the host?
While the container is running I retrieve the data from the db, so there is nothing stored on the filesystem of the container. Even in this case the root user can inject during the execution of the process and "read" that data?

Comment: the container needs to have access to db, which needs to be stored in it somehow, which root user will have access too. As containers are essentially processes, root user may be able to generate core files from them, read /proc/pid/smaps and do other things to it.

Comment: Do you know if there is another alternative? that offers running applications in a container somewhere without allowing access to it?

Comment: If I knew I would add an answer for fake internet points. Unfortunately for you, root can do anything on his machine.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that docker containers which are running on a host machine have root privileges.

This is mostly incorrect. A docker container has root access only on stuff visible to the container; that is directories explicitly mounted onto the container.

> Is it possible to make my container as a "black-box" so I can prevent even the root in the host machine from accessing it?

No. The root user of the machine has access to everything on the machine. There is no way to prevent the root user from having access to the container.

> Are there any other alternatives instead of docker that I can use to achieve this?

You are going to deploy the application in some form on the host, which will result in a runnable process. The root user will always have access and control over this process.
So you which ever approach you take, there is no way to prevent the root user from having access to the application process.